# adding named groups to pyparsing regex inverter

Tags: pyparsing

Hoping Paul McGuire may spot this and rescue me...

I have grabbed the 'regex inverter' example script http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/file/view/invRegex.py

I'm trying to hack in support for python named groups, eg `(?P<blob_key>[a-zA-Z0-9-_=]+)`

I'm new to pyparsing and I realise a regex parser is probably not the best way to learn (I'm just trying to get something practical done with the result).

I have edited the parser function as below:

```python
def parser():
    global _parser
    if _parser is None:
        lbrack = Literal("[")
        rbrack = Literal("]")
        lbrace = Literal("{")
        rbrace = Literal("}")
        lparen = Literal("(")
        rparen = Literal(")")
        pyspec = Literal("?P")
        langle = Literal("<")
        rangle = Literal(">")

        reMacro = Combine("\\" + oneOf(list("dws")))
        escapedChar = ~reMacro + Combine("\\" + oneOf(list(printables)))
        reLiteralChar = "".join(c for c in printables if c not in r"\[]{}().*?+|")

        reRange = Combine(lbrack + SkipTo(rbrack,ignore=escapedChar) + rbrack)
        reLiteral = ( escapedChar | oneOf(list(reLiteralChar)) )
        reDot = Literal(".")
        repetition = (
            ( lbrace + Word(nums).setResultsName("count") + rbrace ) |
            ( lbrace + Word(nums).setResultsName("minCount")+","+ Word(nums).setResultsName("maxCount") + rbrace ) |
            oneOf(list("*+?")) 
            )

        reNamedGroup = Combine(lparen + pyspec + langle + SkipTo(rangle) + rangle
                               + SkipTo(rparen, include=True) + rparen)

        reNamedGroup.setParseAction(handleNamedGroup)
        reRange.setParseAction(handleRange)
        reLiteral.setParseAction(handleLiteral)
        reMacro.setParseAction(handleMacro)
        reDot.setParseAction(handleDot)

        reTerm = ( reLiteral | reNamedGroup | reRange | reMacro | reDot )
        reExpr = operatorPrecedence( reTerm,
            [
            (repetition, 1, opAssoc.LEFT, handleRepetition),
            (None, 2, opAssoc.LEFT, handleSequence),
            (Suppress('|'), 2, opAssoc.LEFT, handleAlternative),
            ]
        )
        _parser = reExpr

    return _parser
```

When I run this against my test regex the `reNamedGroup` seems to find and process the named group correctly (I stuck some logging in `SkipTo` and other methods...) but at the same time it doesn't seem to participate in the output at all and my `handleNamedGroup` function is never called.

The log output looks like:

```
invert(r'serve_blob/[A-Z]{2}/(?P<blob_key>[a-zA-Z0-9-_=]+)/')
DEBUG:root: serve_blob/[A-Z]{2}/(?P<blob_key>[a-zA-Z0-9-_=]+)/, 12
DEBUG:root: *** 15, A-Z
DEBUG:root: serve_blob/[A-Z]{2}/(?P<blob_key>[a-zA-Z0-9-_=]+)/, 12
DEBUG:root: *** 15, A-Z
DEBUG:root: serve_blob/[A-Z]{2}/(?P<blob_key>[a-zA-Z0-9-_=]+)/, 24
DEBUG:root: *** 32, blob_key
DEBUG:root: serve_blob/[A-Z]{2}/(?P<blob_key>[a-zA-Z0-9-_=]+)/, 33
DEBUG:root: * 49, [')'], [a-zA-Z0-9-_=]+
DEBUG:root: ** ['[a-zA-Z0-9-_=]+', ')']
DEBUG:root: serve_blob/[A-Z]{2}/(?P<blob_key>[a-zA-Z0-9-_=]+)/, 24
DEBUG:root: *** 32, blob_key
DEBUG:root: serve_blob/[A-Z]{2}/(?P<blob_key>[a-zA-Z0-9-_=]+)/, 33
DEBUG:root: * 49, [')'], [a-zA-Z0-9-_=]+
DEBUG:root: ** ['[a-zA-Z0-9-_=]+', ')']
DEBUG:root: handleLiteral: ['s']
DEBUG:root: handleLiteral: ['e']
DEBUG:root: handleLiteral: ['r']
DEBUG:root: handleLiteral: ['v']
DEBUG:root: handleLiteral: ['e']
DEBUG:root: handleLiteral: ['_']
DEBUG:root: handleLiteral: ['b']
DEBUG:root: handleLiteral: ['l']
DEBUG:root: handleLiteral: ['o']
DEBUG:root: handleLiteral: ['b']
DEBUG:root: handleLiteral: ['/']
DEBUG:root: serve_blob/[A-Z]{2}/(?P<blob_key>[a-zA-Z0-9-_=]+)/, 12
DEBUG:root: *** 15, A-Z
DEBUG:root: serve_blob/[A-Z]{2}/(?P<blob_key>[a-zA-Z0-9-_=]+)/, 12
DEBUG:root: *** 15, A-Z
DEBUG:root: handleRange: ['[A-Z]']
DEBUG:root: handleRepetition: [[[ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ], '{', '2', '}']]
DEBUG:root: handleLiteral: ['/']
DEBUG:root: serve_blob/[A-Z]{2}/(?P<blob_key>[a-zA-Z0-9-_=]+)/, 24
DEBUG:root: *** 32, blob_key
DEBUG:root: serve_blob/[A-Z]{2}/(?P<blob_key>[a-zA-Z0-9-_=]+)/, 33
DEBUG:root: * 49, [')'], [a-zA-Z0-9-_=]+
DEBUG:root: ** ['[a-zA-Z0-9-_=]+', ')']
DEBUG:root: serve_blob/[A-Z]{2}/(?P<blob_key>[a-zA-Z0-9-_=]+)/, 24
DEBUG:root: *** 32, blob_key
DEBUG:root: serve_blob/[A-Z]{2}/(?P<blob_key>[a-zA-Z0-9-_=]+)/, 33
DEBUG:root: * 49, [')'], [a-zA-Z0-9-_=]+
DEBUG:root: ** ['[a-zA-Z0-9-_=]+', ')']
DEBUG:root: handleSequence: [[Lit:s, Lit:e, Lit:r, Lit:v, Lit:e, Lit:_, Lit:b, Lit:l, Lit:o, Lit:b, Lit:/, <libs.exreg.exreg.GroupEmitter object at 0x34cfa30>, Lit:/]]
```

The lines prefixed with ** are the `skipRes` value returned from `SkipTo` ...it looks correct to me. The part I'm stumped on is why they are being ignored.

I'm acutely aware I'm just copy and pasting stuff around blindly... I've tried to closely copy what works for `reRange`... but range works and my similar bits don't.

I'm guessing maybe the surrounding parentheses are 'hiding' the parsed named group from the output at some later stage of the parsing but I'm lost as to how.

Comment: LOL I have no idea WTF I was trying to do with a regex inverter back in 2012...

Comment: Pyparsing is no longer hosted on wikispaces.com. Go to https://github.com/pyparsing/pyparsing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to do anything with parens in your reNamedGroup expression. Note that there is no other defined grammar for re groups enclosed in parens, but they most definitely work.  In this parser, the parens are handled as part of the operatorPrecedence expression. Just changed your definition of reNamedGroup to:

```python
reNamedGroup = pyspec + langle + SkipTo(rangle) + rangle
```

and let operatorPrecedence take care of all the paren grouping.

**[edited by OP]**
the above change alone sort of works, but all the outputs from the named group begin with either `P` or `?` so the `pyspec` part is leaking into the output somehow. in the end I didn't need to rewrite in stack form (see comments), the following additional change made it work properly:

```python
reTerm = ( reLiteral | reRange | reMacro | reDot )
reExpr = operatorPrecedence( reTerm,
    [
    (reNamedGroup.suppress(), 1, opAssoc.RIGHT, handleNamedGroup),
    (repetition, 1, opAssoc.LEFT, handleRepetition),
    (None, 2, opAssoc.LEFT, handleSequence),
    (Suppress('|'), 2, opAssoc.LEFT, handleAlternative),
    ]
)
```

Comment: you're awesome, thanks it works!  I must admit I don't see how parens are handled by the operatorPrecedence expression here... is that something pyparsing does implicitly, or it is actually defined in this regex grammar somewhere?

Comment: Look at the http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/file/view/fourFn.py example on the pyparsing wiki, and see that ()'s are handled at the lowest level operand, `atom`, enclosing the highest level expression `expr`. Then factor (for mult/div) is defined using atom, and term (for add/sub) is defined using factor. `operatorPrecedence` just packages this process given the base atom expression (without the `(+expr+)` part, opPrec adds that), and the definitions of all of the operations, in ascending precedence order. What makes the regex case unusual is that it supports an operator of None, that is...

Comment: ... just the sequence of successive regex bits in itself is an "operation", the operation of successive re matching. So for you to add support for named groups, you really aren't adding support for groups, that is already in there. What you added was the definition of the leading "?P<name>" bit. Now strictly speaking, putting it in as one of the alternatives in `reTerm`, while it *works*, is not really correct - it means that you would accept "?P<x>?P<y>" as a valid regex, when that is in fact not correct. To inject it into the expression, you would need to pry open the expression created...

Comment: ...by opPrec and inject your naming prefix to be parsed only after the opening '(' of a group definition. opPrec doesn't really expose this, so to define a real re parser that would accept group names, you would need to do a more spelled out form as is done in fourFn.py.

Comment: thanks very much for the detailed pointers, I'll dig into it and try to grok better how it all works

Comment: the `evaluateStack` function is doing the job of operatorPrecedence here? ...so I need to rewrite the current `operatorPrecedence` call in stack form?

Comment: hi, in the end it seems like I didn't have to go down that route... I've edited your answer with the simpler change to the code I found - please edit again and correct or clarify as necessary... thanks!